# Where is the C2DM Source Code?

Tags: android, open-source, push, real-time, android-c2dm

**Anyone know if the C2DM source code is open? If so, where is it located?**

*Just to be clear, I'm not interested in any client code to connect to C2DM, and I'm not interested in any server code to push notifications to C2DM. I'm actually interested in the **source of the C2DM service itself** (the service that's running in the cloud, which handles coordination / registration between clients and application servers).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C2DM is closed source, However if you want to build a push service consider using XMPP. Use OpenFire XMPP Server and aSmack for implementing Push Notification.

Comment: OpenFire looks really interesting. Do you know if people are using this for iOS devices also? I'm currently looking at C2DM for Android and APNS for iOS. However, I wonder if both platforms could be served from a single solution like an OpenFire server?

Comment: I think you need to focus on client, if you are able to build XMPP client for iOS, then you may be successful in pushing data. Sorry i don't have much idea about iOS.

Comment: Looks like there is a iOS client for XMPP, here: https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework

Comment: Well then you can probably work use it to connect to your XMPP Server.

Comment: Do you know if aSmack can receive notifications even when the application is not being used?

Comment: Well you need to create a background service which runs even if application is not in use using aSmack, which would be connected XMPP Server.

Answer (score 1):

It is not open source AFAIK, just as most Google services are not open source AFAIK.